# Could not load file or assembly CMS.Core after upgrade form 8.2 to 9

Tags: c#, .net, kentico

After upgrade from Kentico 8.2 to 9.0 and update to hotfix v9.0.16 my website crashed. It runs once successfully (no errors in log, upgrade start and finish) and after application restart I have got this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CMS.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Full error

https://jsbin.com/defitojura/edit?output

Site is running on Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check your references to custom dlls ?

Comment: Thank you Neshi! Problem was in NewRecaptcha.dll! After refresh references everything is ok, no errors!